# Find the port number of current session in PuTTY

Tags: ssh, ip, putty

I have list of server names in the PuTTY saved sessions. I connected to one session and can know the IP address of the machine connected to using `ifconfig` for Ubuntu and `ipconfig` for Windows. But how to know the port number which has been used in to save those sessions in PuTTY while/after connecting?

I tried `echo "$SSH_CLIENT"` but didn't get the right IP, so, the port might also be wrong.

Comment: from the host side: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54975/how-to-check-that-a-daemon-is-listening-on-what-interface
`ss -nlput | grep sshd` will show `tcp LISTEN  0 0 *:22   *:* sshd 1234 42` -> port 22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your literal question: To find an IP address and a port number of the **current session**:

- Right click PuTTY console window title;
- Select *Event Log*;
- The very first entry in the log says:

  ```
  Connecting to <ip> port <port>
  ```

  [image]

---

*Though in majority of cases the port will be 22, as that's the standard SSH port.*

Answer (score 8):

After spending some time with putty, I figured out myself.

In putty configuration, click name in the **Saved Sessions**, then click **Load** button, one can see the port number in the above **Port** field.

> Open Putty -> select Session -> Load -> See the Port Field

*Sometimes, simple things just doesn't get easily caught with our eyes.*